# Ionic 3: Custom angular component not working as expected. Bug?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Basically there is a wrapping problen in which dom element of custom component does not cover their children.

There is a `single` page which uses test component.

**single.html**

```
<test></test>
```

**single.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-single',
  templateUrl: 'single.html',
})
export class SinglePage {}
```

**single.scss**

```
page-single {}
```

Now this `test` component

**test.html**

```
<div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

**test.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

test.scss

```
test {}
```

[image: inspect mode in chrome]

1. Why it looks `test` and inside `div` elements are siblings to `test` and are not like parent child?
2. Changing `background-color:red` on `test` (in chrome inspect mode) does nothing visually, meaning all children div color remains same.

Full `test` element is not highlighted. Inside `div` elements are fine. `test` component shows `411 x 68` but looks like it is `0x0`. Computed styles show dimension as `auto x auto`. Every component in my app is behaving like this. Component do not cover their child and looks like their sibling.

This behaviour was also present in Ionic example conference app. In Angular example app components works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:host { display:block; background:red; }` in `test.scss`

This is because browsers don't recognize `<test>` as a a block element. Other than that, it's working as intended and if you look at the dom tree more carefully, you'll see that the div is inside test.

:host is a pseudo which refers to the component element itself - `test {}` does nothing unless there's another test inside like `<test><test></test></test>`, then it'd affect the child.